# Error: Element is not clickable. Other element would receive the click

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In selenium test execution I'm getting:

> unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point
>   (1147, 21). Other element would receive the click: < span
>   id="schoolName_">...       (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)

Code starts from here:

```
List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary']"));
        for (WebElement firstbutton : button) {

            int count = 1;
            System.out.println("count is " + count + " Hence it should click he button if button is displayed : ");
            if (count == 1) {

                // ((JavascriptExecutor)
                // driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)");
                // act.moveToElement(firstbutton).click();
                firstbutton.click();
                System.out.println("Save button is clicked");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Button is already clicked");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use focus or scroll on that element. You also might have to use explict wait.

```
WebElement firstbutton= driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your Element"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

OR

The element is not clickable because of a Spinner/Overlay on top of it:

```
By loadingImage = By.id("loading image ID");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(loadingImage));
```

OR

```
Point p= element.getLocation();
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).movebyoffset(p.x,p.y).click().perform();
```

OR

If still not work use `JavascriptExecutor`

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", firstbutton);
```

Comment: Hi @Shubham, while using action class, it works correctly for chrome browser but its not working in mozilla. But javascriptExecutor is working in the both the browser and I'm able to click on the element. Thanks for your help.

Comment: instead of click, how would you enter, say "George Washington", into a text field? (firstbutton is an input instead of a button). arguments[0].sendKeys(arguments[1]) ?

Comment: its an separate question which you need to raise as per stack guidelines . still you can try something like this : JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript(“document.getElementsById(‘some_id’).value=’Avinash Mishra’;”);